# Divide Page into Two independent Columns with Different Backgrounds

Tags: parcolumns, page

I wish to divide my page into two independent columns from each other (one large 33% of the page width) and with different background colors. 
Which is the best strategy to do this? I also would like to set margin into the columns so I started by putting zero the margins of the page. The class i'm using is "letter".

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a picture of what you want to achieve? And please add which documentclass you are using (even better: a minimal, compilable code example).

Comment: Here there is a wonderful answer of Christian https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310988/two-columns-with-different-background-color-and-height-of-whole-page