# Unable to put name on top of two columns || change color borders of left column

Tags: tcolorbox, two-column, geometry

I am interested to make a two columns resume. I took sample from deedy, but was unable to add colors to it; I searched and found link ([Two columns with different background color and height of whole page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310988/two-columns-with-different-background-color-and-height-of-whole-page)).

However, there are two challenges:

1. John Doe is on first page and columns begin from next page
2. I'd like to make the black border between two columns go away or reduce its width

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{deedy-resume} % Use US Letter paper, change to a4paper for A4  \usepackage{geometry} \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lastupdated % Print the Last Updated text at the top right

\namesection{John}{Doe}{ % Your name

\href{mailto:name@gmail.com}{name@gmail.com} | 70000 00000 % Your contact information }

\newtcolorbox{bgbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,leftright skip=0pt,boxrule=0pt,enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners,#1}

\noindent %\begin{bgbox}[height=\paperheight,colback=gray!22,width=0.5\textwidth,rightrule=10pt,colframe=black] \begin{bgbox}[height=\paperheight,colback=gray!22,width=0.5\textwidth,rightrule=10pt] \section{Education} 

\subsection{Samsung Institute of Science} \descript{MS Pharmacy} \subsection{Rubber social Science} \descript{BS Nursing}

\sectionsep % Some whitespace after the section

\section{Links} 

Github:// \href{https://github.com/jay2205}{\bf jay2205} \\ LinkedIn:// \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/jayanthdevulapally}{\bf jayanthdevulapally} \\

\section{Skills} \sectionsep % Some whitespace after the section

\subsection{Programming}

\textbullet{} python, R, LaTeX \\

\end{bgbox}% \begin{bgbox}[height=\paperheight,colback=white,width=0.7\textwidth] \section{Experience}


\runsubsection{Senior Data Scientist } \\ %\descript{Student Employee, Kent State University | April 2015 - present} \descript{Company name | Nov 2021 - present} \vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space \begin{tightemize} \item Updating the features of KSU mobile iOS app for every quarter year. %\item Maintaining the iOS applications based on the crash report. \end{tightemize} \descript{Projects:} \textbullet{} {\bf KSU Mobile Q2 and Q3 – iOS application} \begin{tightemize} \item {\bf Dinning Plan Matrix View}: Developed split view of Table View and Graph View that helps user to track expenses. \item {\bf Student Center Parking Status}: Developed to show number of parking slots are available.

\end{tightemize} \textbullet{} {\bf S.L.A.T.E} (Science Learning and Teaching Evaluation) - iPad Application \begin{tightemize} \item Designed and Architected complete iPad Application. \item MVC framework implementation to record responses for all questions.

\end{tightemize} \sectionsep % Some whitespace after the section

\runsubsection{Staff Associate} \\ \descript{Another company name | Oct 2017 - Oct 2021}

\descript{Projects:}

\textbullet{} {\bf KuKu-Cubes}(iOS Application) \begin{tightemize} \item Designed the views and game flow with UICollectionView and Navigation controller.

{\bf App Store}:// \href{https://appsto.re/us/Jpit5.i}{https://appsto.re/us/Jpit5.i} \end{tightemize}

\runsubsection{Research Associate} \\

\descript{Some more company | Feb 2015 – Oct 2017} \begin{tightemize} \item Developed a dynamic module to fetch information from Content management system and publish on web. \item Maintained the online results module which fetch data from JNTU server and publish in the student portal.\\ \end{tightemize}

\sectionsep % Some whitespace after the section

\runsubsection{Web Developer} \\ \descript{IT Services | June -2011 – July 2013 } \begin{tightemize}

\item Engineered dynamic photo gallery, which fetch the data from content management.\\ \end{tightemize}

\end{bgbox} \end{document}
```

How do I edit and get desired results?

Thank you

Comment: I can't compile your code, even though I downloaded a required file from [the link](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume) in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/666993/31283) of yours. Is a problem related to this specific document class? Can you use `article` and standard fonts in your [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)? A good test would be to compile your code on Overleaf. If it's not working there, it's likely it will not work on my side and I won't be able to help.

Comment: @Celdor that is OK. Thank you. It requires xelatex to compile. Thank you for your time

Comment: @DeathMetal it may be easier to make the resume directly with TiKz/TEX rather than changing the syntax in the `deedy resume` - if so upload a drawing of the resume you require

Comment: @jsbibra thank you for your inputs. Yes, I realized `deedy` resume isn't something I'd like, hence I went with my design. I'm using `res.cls` for my own idea. I'll certainly upload a drawing of the desired resume.